# SPSS: Changed color settings for model viewer

Tags: spss

how do I changed the color for significant lines in SPSS model viewer for nonparametric results?

currently, the display is in orange lines. I dont see any options in Edit> Options > Viewer > Model Viewer.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your preference setting in Edit > Options > Output to "pivot tables and charts", the output will appear in traditional form.  You can double click a chart, which opens it in the Graphboard editor (rather than the more familiar Chart Editor), where some editing is possible.  However, chart elements that are structural, i.e., that come from the chart logic, generally cannot be changed as this could violate the chart integrity.

It would be better if the Graphboard Stylesheet option choices applied to these charts, but currently they don't.  It is possible to edit the standard stylesheet, but this is quite difficult and I wouldn't recommend it.  I'm not sure that even then it would affect these charts.

Comment: Thanks @JKP. i think this could really not be changed.